# How to convert from version 2 to version without getting undecleared indentiier error in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

Trying to convert from version 2 to version getting undeclared identifier error in pine script. The line is as below

```
src= close 
length1= 35 
length2= 20
siglength= 10 
ebc= false

calc_csf(src, length) => 
    sm = 2.0/length
    csf=(src - csf[1]) * sm + csf[1]
    csf
i=(src/nz(src[1], src))*100
```

**However, it gives me**

```
line 258: Undeclared identifier 'csf'
```

Using a **suggestion from below answer**, I changed it to below

```
src= close 
length1= 35 
length2= 20
siglength= 10 
ebc= false


calc_csf(src, length) => 
    sm = 2.0/length
    csf = 0
    csf := (src - nz(csf[1])) * sm + nz(csf[1])
    csf
i=(src/nz(src[1], src))*100
```

However, I am getting

```
Processing script...
Variable 'csf' was declared with 'series[integer]' type. Cannot assign it expression of type 'series[float]'.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what's needed without more context. You could try this, but make sure you compare results with previous version's output:

```
csf = 0.
csf := (src - nz(csf[1])) * sm + nz(csf[1])
```

If this doesn't work, post more context.

Comment: Hi . Thank you so much. However, using that suggestion you gave, I am getting a new error. This is so confusing. Please help. Thank you so much.

Comment: There's a decimal point after the zero in `csf = 0.`; it's important in order to declare the variable as a float.